# How to render my view when initial value is delayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I have a component that holds a single boolean in state and renders a button that toggles that value.
The value of the boolean comes from an object that is created in a parent component. When the object is created the button is displayed but the actual value of the boolean is set slightly later by another process.

[image: Edit broken-shape-wrnkhn]

```
const Child = ({ obj }) => {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(obj.aBool);

  useEffect(() => {
    obj.aBool = bool;
    console.log(obj);
  }, [bool]);

  const toggle = () => {
    setBool(!bool);
  }

  return <button onClick={toggle}>
    Value is {bool!=undefined?bool.toString():'...'}
  </button>
}
```

The button renders while the boolean is undefined and the view reflects this. The boolean is then set later by a `setTimeout` which you can see if you open the console.
But the value does not reflect in the button until you click, after which is works fine.

Is there a way to watch the object property so that when it updates after 2 seconds the button re-renders to reflect the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that the `obj` prop that is passed to `Child` isn't part of any React state and its object reference never changes, it's only mutated. There's no way for React to know that anything changed and that anything needs to be rerendered.

## Solution

Make `obj` state in the parent component and pass it and the `toggle` function down as props to the `Child` component. When the state updates in the parent then the `Child` component will be automatically rerendered.

Example:

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState({ // <-- part of React state
    aBool: undefined
  });

  useEffect(() => { // <-- side-effect to set/update the state
    setTimeout(() => {
      setObj({
        aBool: true
      });
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  const toggle = () => { // <-- handler to toggle aBool value
    setObj((obj) => ({
      ...obj,
      aBool: !obj.aBool
    }));
  };

  return <Child obj={obj} toggle={toggle} />; // <-- obj and toggle passed as props
}
```

Child

```
import React from "react";

const Child = ({ obj, toggle }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={toggle}>
      Value is {obj.aBool != undefined ? obj.aBool.toString() : "..."}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

### Demo

[image: Edit how-to-render-my-view-when-initial-value-is-delayed]

Comment: This is the second one of my noob questions you've answered in as many days. Much appreciated :) So when I "listen" to state with useEffect dependencies, it doesn't actually care about the underlying raw value at all? I can mutate that as much as I want with no effect?
I'm slowly getting there and this has steered me through the latest issue. Look out for my next question soon, I'm sure this is far from my last ;)

Comment: @popClingwrap "So when I "listen" to state with useEffect dependencies, it doesn't actually care about the underlying raw value at all?" - Yes.... and no. React cares about reference equality. If the state reference changes, React will rerender. Primitives like numbers and primitive-like like strings are *always* self-reference equal, e.g. `5` always equals `5` and `"foo"` always equals `"foo"` regardless of the variable reference. This is why it is ***extremely*** important to ***not*** mutate state/prop references. It negates React's checks to ensure the correct values are rendered.

Comment: @popClingwrap Just keep in mind that "Thou shalt not mutate objects!" is a React commandment.

Comment: Thanks again. I have had a proper comb through my code and I did find an instance where I was mutating an object directly. I've fixed that now and all is running smooth

Comment: @popClingwrap Awesome, great to hear. Welcome, and cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're looking to maybe use [Suspense](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense) which has a fallback until something has finished loading.

I threw a small example together in codepen, I hope it help.

https://codepen.io/huzi8t9/pen/GRzEqpX

```js
import React, { useState, lazy } from "https://esm.sh/react";
import ReactDOM from "https://esm.sh/react-dom";

const SuspensfulComponent = lazy(() => {
  
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve({ default: () => <p>Loaded </p> })
        }, 5000);
    })
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<p>Wait...</p>}>
      <SuspensfulComponent />
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));

root.render(<App />);
```

The above example will show "Wait..." until the promise is resolved in the `SuspensefulComponent` -- the component will return some basic text but, if you had genuine data loading inside your component, Suspense would fire and fallback when loading is happening.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't need to duplicate the state in the Child. It outta just rerender when the parent changes.

Not sure if this is what you were looking for. Hope it helps!

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-chaplygin-46d38q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js:0-45